# How to pass request-id in quarkus through activeMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic, quarkus, vert.x, mdc

My application is generating a request and then sending that request to a listener(activemq here) for further processing, I am trying to add a request-id to the logs for better tracing of errors but the request-id is not passing to the listener it works fine before that, i have tried the approach mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70892802/19343662

These are the files i have created...

RequestIdFilter:

```
package com.cashfree.common.dexterreport.filters;

import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerRequest;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import org.slf4j.MDC;

@Provider
public class RequestIdFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

  @Context
  HttpServerRequest request;

  private static final String REQUEST_ID_HEADER_NAME = "X-Request-Id";
  private static final String REQUEST_ID = "requestId";

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) {
    MDC.put(REQUEST_ID, getRequestIdFromHeader(request));
  }

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
    MDC.remove(REQUEST_ID);
  }

  private String getRequestIdFromHeader(final HttpServerRequest request) {
    String requestId = request.getHeader(REQUEST_ID_HEADER_NAME);
    if (requestId == null || requestId.length() == 0) {
      requestId = generateUniqueRequestId();
    }
    return requestId;
  }

  private String generateUniqueRequestId() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }
}
```

MdcContextProvider

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.context.spi.ThreadContextProvider;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.context.spi.ThreadContextSnapshot;
import org.slf4j.MDC;

public class MdcContextProvider implements ThreadContextProvider {

  @Override
  public ThreadContextSnapshot currentContext(Map<String, String> props) {
    Map<String, String> propagate = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
    return () -> {
      Map<String, String> old = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
      MDC.setContextMap(propagate);
      return () -> {
        MDC.setContextMap(old);
      };
    };
  }

  @Override
  public ThreadContextSnapshot clearedContext(Map<String, String> props) {
    return () -> {
      Map<String, String> old = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
      MDC.clear();
      return () -> {
        MDC.setContextMap(old);
      };
    };
  }

  @Override
  public String getThreadContextType() {
    return "SLF4J MDC";
  }
}
```

A ThreadContextProvider file created at `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.eclipse.microprofile.context.spi.ThreadContextProvider` having line specifying the ref path of mdcContextProvider : `com.org.common.report.Provider.MdcContextProvider`

But this is not working although i was expecting this, since the the thread started by listener and the thread which passes the message to it has no connection between them, is there any way where i can pass the request-id to the listener...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with a workaround.

Because each Listener runs/spawn up its own thread. you cannot expect the request ID to be available in MDC property as MDC property is thread local.

I was able to achieve it by passing the value as part of ActiveMQ's message

Example:
Wrap every message you exchange in a Generic class

```
class ActiveMqMsg {
   private Message message;
   private Map<String, Object> properties;
}
```

and expect Listener to deserialize it to `ActiveMqMsg` and read the properties and set it to MDC property again.

Hope this helps.